# Procedural Noise Texture with Image

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I saw a tutorial about Procedural Noise texture, but I want to add an image on the surface of the texture.
I set up the Nodes but cant figure the correct order to get my image showing.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: you need to plug the Bump in the Normal socket of the Principled, I guess that's what you want to do...

Comment: Thanks heaps for that, it was exactly what I was after.I needed to manipulate the settings of the bump strength to get the image to show trough, because the higher the strength the image was getting buried into the mesh.

https://ibb.co/pwSn7kK

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plug the *Bump* node in the *Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF*.